# MySQL JOIN around subquery result

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have this query (notice that all 3 subqueries are selecting different columns from the same row). Essentially I want to get the rows in `product_bid` with the maximum date alongside the `product` row.

```
SELECT 
p.product_id,
p.product_title, 
(SELECT b.bid_id FROM product_bids b WHERE b.bid_product_id=p.product_id ORDER BY b.bid_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS bid_id,
(SELECT b.bid_date FROM product_bids b WHERE b.bid_product_id=p.product_id ORDER BY b.bid_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS bid_date,
(SELECT b.bid_amount FROM product_bids b WHERE b.bid_product_id=p.product_id ORDER BY b.bid_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS bid_amount

FROM product p

WHERE p.product_auction_id=325
```

Is there a way to do the subquery once to get the PK of `product_bids`, and join on that (the result of the subquery) or any clean way of doing this?

*Side Note*: Would the query optimiser recognise this anyway, making it less important?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your tables together with a subquery that selects the latest bid date for each product:

```
SELECT p.product_id, b.bid_id, b.bid_date, b.bid_amount
FROM   product_bids AS b NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT   bid_product_id, MAX(bid_date) AS bid_date
         FROM     product_bids
         GROUP BY bid_product_id
       ) AS t
  JOIN product AS p ON p.product_id = b.bid_product_id
WHERE  p.product_auction_id = 325
```

Comment: This is perfect except that my original query also returned products with no corresponding rows in `product_bids`. Can one of these be a `left join` instead?

Comment: @Adam: Yes, absolutely (although as I've ordered them, you'll actually want to `RIGHT JOIN product ...`).

Comment: Just figured that out as you posted it. Thanks. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it inside one SQL query might be tough, but I have this proposal. Select the maximum date from product_bids first, then make a second query like this:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_title, b.bid_id, b.bid_date, b.bid_amount
from product p
inner join product_bids b on b.bid_date = @yourselectedbiddate
```

This should fetch exactly the same data, but with much higher performance. Note that the @yourselectedbiddate needs to amount to a value that exactly one record has, otherwise you will multiply lines, which you do not want. If this is not the case (which means that you cannot rely on one being the top), you have a similar problem with your proposal, as you have not defined which of the records with the maximum date comes first.